# nginx: emerg: unknown "request_url" variable

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to configure an Nginx Server on Ubuntu on a Droplet at Digital Ocean.

When I run `sudo nginx -t`, I am getting an error

`[emerg] unknown "request_url" variable` and also says something about the etc/nginx/nginx.conf file but I don't see "request_url" being used anywhere in the below file.

Here's my `default` config file

```
# Enforce HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Proxy all requests to Node
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.storybook.space;

    # Use the Let's Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I've tried searching for answers about this, but none could solve my problem.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working.

Looks like it was something to do with caching (may not be the right word), etc.
I created a new VM and performed the same steps on it. Works perfectly with and without SSL.

Previously, while setting this up, I accidently entered `$host$request_url` instead of `$host$request_uri` once and since then I've been getting this error

Hope it helps!